# Roslyn - Limit What Script Can Do

Tags: scripting, roslyn

I am trying to validate a user-provided script - based on C# syntax.
I only want to accept scripts that handle basic math operations and some functions I control. I can't allow any type of .DoSomething() notation.
Example, user can do this:
String.ToUpper("foo"), but not "foo".ToUpper() - I need to be in control of everything I allow to be executed from these. Note, that I have my own String.ToUpper implementation - just calls the underlying .net, but it has to go through my facade.

I am not sure what Syntax visitors to use for something like this. Is there an easy way to do something like this: flag *any* method invocations that don't come from classes that implement a specific marker interface that I control?

Basically, if I am going to attempt to execute user-provided code, I want to make absolutely sure only a specific set of operations can be executed.

TIA

Comment: This is a not an easy problem btw, there are a couple of similar applications that have the same requirements (i.e. coding sandboxes in the browser), and most of those use a container-based approach nowadays. You might wanna take a look at something like [Unbreakable](https://github.com/ashmind/Unbreakable), which implemented API-based filtering. Unless your allowed API is _very_ small, you might want to check other approaches.

Comment: Thanks @Lennart, agreed, and security is a very major concern (which is why the whitelist of what can be called).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for myself (so far). This looks like it finds all invocations and verifies if the type that implements the method inherits from my interface. Any issues with this?

```
var invocationExpressionVisitor = new InvocationExpressionVisitor();
     invocationExpressionVisitor.Visit(root);
     var invocations = invocationExpressionVisitor.Invocations;

     foreach (InvocationExpressionSyntax invocation in invocations)
     {
        ISymbol symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol;
        if (symbol != null)
        {
           INamedTypeSymbol containingType = symbol.ContainingType;
           if (containingType.Interfaces.All(i => i.MetadataName != nameof(ISomeControlledInterface)))
           {
              ValidationMessages.Add("Expression uses disallowed method invocations.");
           }
        }
     }
```